# How to use a SUM, LEFT JOIN, group by and order by in one SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I am trying to construct a query I can use within my ASP.NET code that pulls from a data base and then exports it into an excel file. My goal is to have SQL do most of the work before I iterate onto my worksheet. This is my code before using sum and group by

```
SELECT EOD_Rental_Fees.*, POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails.description as TotalFeeAmount)
FROM EOD_Rental_Fees
LEFT JOIN POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails ON EOD_Rental_Fees.CoreBankingID = POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails.ID 
WHERE DateProcessed >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000'
AND DateProcessed <= '2018-08-30 00:00:00:000'          
ORDER BY description, DateProcessed;
```

This is the result of it:[image]

When I add SUM or GROUP BY like so

```
 Select  EOD_Rental_Fees.*, POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails.description, (Select SUM (EOD_Rental_Fees.TotalFee) as TotalFeeAmount) from 
            EOD_Rental_Fees
            LEFT JOIN POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails ON EOD_Rental_Fees.CoreBankingID = POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails.ID 
            WHERE DateProcessed >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000'
            AND DateProcessed <= '2018-08-30 00:00:00:000'
            Group By Currency
            Order By description, DateProcessed;
```

I get the following error:[image] I am trying to have a column that shows TotalFeeAmount that is grouped by Currency.
From what I can see my query looks fine. What am I doing wrong to cause this?

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data for both tables and also show us the exact output you would expect based on that sample data.

Comment: It is necessary to know which database you use, and version, none of the chosen tags sufficiently narrow down  the solution options. e.g. MySQL 8+ will be different to MySQL 5x

Comment: Apologies I have added sql-server to the tags. Thanks!

Comment: what is SUM (EOD_Rental_Fees.TotalFee) showing? grouping per currency doesn't make sense

Comment: Please post code, data and *errors* as formatted text - not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep adding to the question which makes it difficult to answer. In the latest image you are displaying a report - not a query result, so I am going to ignore the sub-totals and that i something for your presentation layer to deal with.

"*From what I can see my query looks fine*" Sorry, it isn't fine because it produces SQL errors. That error actually tells you that if you want to use group by you must specify which columns to be grouped by. Your query does not do that.

To avoid that error every "non-aggregating" column needs to be spelled out in the group by clause like so (note you cannot use * for this)

```
SELECT 
      rf.id
    , rf.year
    , rf.month
    , rf.DateProcessed
    , rf.CoreBankingID
    , rf.MerchantRecordID
    , rf.DeployedDate 
    , rf.TerminalRecordID
    , rf.DeployedDate
    , rf.RecoveredDate
    , rf.MonthlyFee
    , rf.IsProRated
    , rf.DaysActive
    , rf.TotalFee
    , rf.IsPinPad
    , rf.Currency
    , det.description
    , sum(rf.TotalFee) as TotalFeeAmount
FROM EOD_Rental_Fees AS rf
LEFT JOIN POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails as det ON rf.CoreBankingID = det.ID
WHERE rf.DateProcessed >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000'
   AND rf.DateProcessed < '2018-09-01 00:00:00:000'
GROUP BY
      rf.id
    , rf.year
    , rf.month
    , rf.DateProcessed
    , rf.CoreBankingID
    , rf.MerchantRecordID
    , rf.DeployedDate 
    , rf.TerminalRecordID
    , rf.DeployedDate
    , rf.RecoveredDate
    , rf.MonthlyFee
    , rf.IsProRated
    , rf.DaysActive
    , rf.TotalFee
    , rf.IsPinPad
    , rf.Currency
    , det.description
ORDER BY
      det.description
    , rf.DateProcessed
```

However I suspect this isn't going to produce the wanted outcome because you are after both details and summary at the same time which `GROUP BY` isn't designed to achieve.

I think you will find using `SUM() OVER()` will be closer to you need, but exactly how you need the `PARTITION BY` subclause to work isn't clear to me. notwithstanding this may work for you:

```
SELECT 
      rf.id
    , rf.year
    , rf.month
    , rf.DateProcessed
    , rf.CoreBankingID
    , rf.MerchantRecordID
    , rf.DeployedDate 
    , rf.TerminalRecordID
    , rf.DeployedDate
    , rf.RecoveredDate
    , rf.MonthlyFee
    , rf.IsProRated
    , rf.DaysActive
    , rf.TotalFee
    , rf.IsPinPad
    , rf.Currency
    , det.description
    , sum(rf.TotalFee) over(partition by rf.CoreBankingID, Currency) as TotalFeeAmount
FROM EOD_Rental_Fees AS rf
LEFT JOIN POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails as det ON rf.CoreBankingID = det.ID
WHERE rf.DateProcessed >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000'
   AND rf.DateProcessed < '2018-09-01 00:00:00:000'
ORDER BY
      det.description
    , rf.DateProcessed
```

Notes:

1. Use table aliases to simplify your queries
2. when joining tables include the table aliases in all column references
3. I subtly changed the way the date range works, always use a combination of >= with < and the upper boundary is "the next day". With this approach you cover yourself for any data rows that have both date and time.

Comment: Hey thanks very much! I kept adding to it to give more details and make it easier for people to understand what I was looking for. Sorry about that!

Comment: Please note the change of the date range in the where clause. When working with datetime data it is easy to make mistakes that could exclude the duration of the final day.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it by using `GROUP BY ROLLUP`:

```
Select
    DESCRIPTION
    , currency
    , DateProcessed 
    SUM (EOD_Rental_Fees.TotalFee)
from
    EOD_Rental_Fees
LEFT JOIN POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails 
    ON EOD_Rental_Fees.CoreBankingID = POSH5_Prod_CoreBankingDetails.ID
WHERE
    DateProcessed >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND DateProcessed <= '2018-08-30 00:00:00:000'
GROUP BY ROLLUP (DESCRIPTION, currency, DateProcessed)
Order By
    description,DateProcessed;
```